# Hopf-Rinow, the exponential map, and a closed bounded set

Tags: differential-geometry

I am taking a differential geometry class but we skipped the proof of Hopf-Rinow so I am struggling to piece this argument together: I am allowed to use the fact the Hopf-Rinow guarentees the existence of a geodesic connectioning any two points on the manifold

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a complete and connected Riemannian manifold. Then the closed and bounded subsets are compact.

Proof: Suppose $T$ is a closed and bounded subset of $M$. For fixed $p\in M$, there is an $R>0$ such that $T\subset B_R(p)$. By Hopf-Rinow, there exists a geodesic joining $p$ and any point $q\in T$. (Now here is the part I don't get) Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $T\subset B_R(p)\subset \exp_p(\overline{B_\epsilon (0)})$. Since the exponential map takes compact sets to compact sets, $T$ is a closed subset of a compact set, hence compact.

What is most confusing is how we used the fact "there exists a geodesic joining any two points in the manifold".

I think this means that for fixed $p\in M$, given and $q\in M$, there exists a $v_q\in T_pM$ such that $\exp_p(v_q)=\gamma_q(1)=q$, where $\gamma_q$ is the geodesic joining $p$ to $q$. But i don't understand how we can find an $\epsilon$-ball around $0$ in $T_p M$ which contains all the desired vectors. What if the vectors needed are not a bounded set in $T_p M$, and hence cannot fit in any ball?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path. We know that for any $q\in T$, there exist $v_q$ with the length $\epsilon_q$ such that $\exp_p(v_q)=\gamma_q(1)=q$. So now we have an open cover of $T$ as
$$
\{ \exp(B_{\epsilon_q}(0)) : \epsilon_q \text{ is the lenght of } v_q \text{ assumed above } \}
$$
Now use compactness of $T$ to find the desired $\epsilon_{max}$ and its subset $\exp(B_{\epsilon_{max}}(0))$ that cover $T$.